# SSL POSTGRES connection with self-signed certificate

Tags: postgresql, ssl, teamsql

I'm new on SSL, so I've started by reading lot of tutorials, topics, forum...
There is lot of information, and it's a bit complicated.
I'm trying to make a SSL connection between my computer and a Postgresql instance on a different server. To do that, I've worked step by step.

1. Check that the connection between the two is working without SSL

   - connect myself by command line: OK !

   psql "hostaddr=X.X.X.X port=5432 user=postgres dbname=my_db"

   - connect myself by a DB visual tool (TeamSql, it's like PgAdmin or MysqlWorkbench): OK !
2. Generate keys and certificates;
   I've followed a tutorial online (everything following in "[]" is a parameter that I've hide)

Create the server key

```
openssl genrsa -des3 -out server.key 1024
chmod 400 server.key
chown postgres.postgres server.key
openssl req -new -key server.key -days 3650 -out server.crt -x509 -subj '/C=FR/ST=[MyCountry]/L=[MyCity]/O=[MyCompany]/CN=postgres/emailAddress=[my@email.com]'
```

Assume that the root certificate is the same

```
cp server.crt root.crt
```

After that, generate client side. First, the key

```
openssl genrsa -des3 -out /tmp/postgresql.key 1024
```

Then the CSR

```
openssl req -new -key /tmp/postgresql.key -out /tmp/postgresql.csr -subj '/C=FR/ST=[MyCountry]/L=[MyCity]/O=[MyCompany]/CN=postgres'
```

And finally the CRT

```
openssl x509 -req -in /tmp/postgresql.csr -CA root.crt -CAkey server.key -out /tmp/postgresql.crt -CAcreateserial
```

3. Activation of SSL on server side.
   In the PG_HBA.CONF file, add a specific line to handles SSL connections from outside

[image]

In the POSTGRESQL.CONF file, modify those lines:

```
listen_addresses = '*'
[...]
ssl = on
[...]
ssl_cert_file = 'server.crt'
ssl_key_file = 'server.key'
ssl_ca_file = 'root.crt'
```

4. Retrieves postgresql.key, postgresql.crt and root.crt files on my computer, in the /home/user/.postgresql/ folder. 
   Also changed rights on the postgresql.key file (600)
5. Try the first step again. In case of command line, everything is ok. But with the visual tool, even with the SSL option activated (and using the same three files) there is two results:

   - with "Reject Unauthorized" option set to OFF: it's working
   - with "Reject Unauthorized" option set to ON: got an error

> Hostname/IP doesn't match certificate's altnames: "IP: X.X.X.X is not
>   in the cert's list: "

(with X.X.X.X my server IP)

So my question is: did I do everything fine? Why there is a difference between the command line connection and the visual tool one?
Is the certificates generation's ok?

Of course, I don't want a real CA Certification. I'm looking for a self-signed one, but even if I've followed different tutorials, it's still not working...
Thanks for your help and have a good weekend

Answer (score 2):

> openssl req -new ... CN=postgres ...

The CN in the server cert should match the hostname (or IP address) by which the server will be addressed by the client, which in your case would be `X.X.X.X`, not `postgres`.

Alternatively, the SAN in the cert could match, but you aren't using any SAN.

The default for `psql` is not to check that the CN or SAN in the cert agrees with the host specified to connect to (which is a pretty lousy default in my opinion), which is why that one works by default.

You should remake the server cert so that it includes the host name/IP address in either the CN or the SAN.  Or if you don't want to, then leave "Reject Unauthorized" set to off.

Also, TeamSQL appears to be defunct.  You might want to switch to a different tool which is currently supported and has better documentation.

Answer (score 1):

I believe it's because psql will connect over SSL without verifying the certs, and TeamSql is doing full verification (default in JDBC as far as I'm aware) so is rejecting the cert.

If you include the "sslmode=verify-full" flag with psql you should get the same response as TeamSql.

Comment: There is too much speculation and asking in this post and not enough answering. Please wait for your commenting privilege for this kind of contribution. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead